# Exporting results of supervised classification using Ecognition

Tags: qgis, symbology, ecognition

I am trying to export the result of the classification. I set the parameters as below. However, when I open the shapefile in QGIS, there's no category called "class name". Thus, I can't change the symbology.

How can I fix that, and present the classified map with QGIS?

[image: The screenshot of Export Result]

Comment: Could it be storing the class names in a different field?